# Doing bitwise complement on a 16-bit signal (Python) operator ^

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Small question, I'm trying to do the bitwise complement (NOT) of a signal that is 16-bit long. In Python from the documentation, I naively thought that doing the following would work:

```
~ x
```

To my surprise this returns negative numbers. I asked in a chat and they told me to use:

```
x ^ 65535
```

The thing that I still do not understand is why this works.

Why does this work?

Comment: Short answer: `~x` inverts _all_ the bits of `x` including its sign bit. `x ^ 65536` (or `x ^ 0xffff`) inverts just the lower 16-bits of `x`.

Comment: @martineau - Almost! 0xffff is 65535. `x ^ 65536` just adds 0x10000 to the number.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, I incorporated that into my answer. And that's proof that its probably better to use 0xffff - less chance of a bug ;)

Comment: @tdelaney: Good catch, I missed the char folks incorrectly told the OP to use 65536 instead of the correct value of 65535 (or 0xfff). Technically `x ^ 65536` inverts the 17th bit of `x`, so if its value was `0x1`, the result would be `0x10001` (or 35537) — which just happens to be the same as adding them together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~x` inverts all the bits of x including its sign bit. `x ^ 65535` inverts just the lower 16-bits of x.

The `^` means bitwise XOR operation. The truth table for single bit a XOR b is:

```
a b | a^b
---------
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1    <-
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0    <-
```

XOR has an interesting property that `a ^ 0 = a` (identity) and `a ^ 1 = not a` (invert). You can see this in the `<-` lines in the above table.

So what `x ^ 65535` (or `x ^ 0xffff` which is clearer) does is bitwise XOR the lower 16 bits with 16 ones to invert just the lower 16 bits (0xffff == 65535 is 16 ones). So for a 32 bit example:

```
       xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
xor    0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
----------------------------------------------
       xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA (where A is ~a)
```

The x's represent bits that remain the same in the input and result. The A's represent bits that have been inverted.

BTW: another way to do the same thing would have been:

```
~x & 0xffff
```